# sqlite: looks like moveToNext works without moveToFirst needed

Tags: android, sqlite

After creating a standard SQLite cursor, I'm iterating thru the entries using:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
}
```

All the rows are being processed correctly.
All the documentation I've read states you need to issue a `moveToFirst()` to ensure
that you're pointing to the first entry of the cursor set.

Is this working even though it shouldn't,
and another release may not have the same processing?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

No, this is working correctly.  `Cursor`s begin at row index -1 (before the first row).  If the `Cursor` references multiple rows, looping through them with the `while` loop as you have suggested is the preferred method.  It will call `moveToNext()`, which moves you to index 0 (the first row), and go from there.

If your `Cursor` only references one row, you may call `moveToFirst()` on it before reading data to ensure that you are on a valid index.  Both `moveToFirst()` and `moveToNext()` have the same effect when the `Cursor` is first created and is at index -1.

Comment: Thanks! That explains why its been working consistently. Strange that none of the examples I've seen specify that this is a way you can iterate thru a cursor.

Comment: +1, Very awesome analysis. This is also [documented here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getPosition()).

Comment: "which moves you to index 0 (the first row)"
Correctly it moves to index 1 from index -1 skipping 0.