# get contact list on HTC desire in android

Tags: android

i want to get a contact list on list view. and i am able to show using this code.

```
private ContactList getContacts() {
        ContactList contactList = new ContactList();
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER };

        Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null,
                null);

        int indexName = people
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int indexNumber = people
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

        people.moveToFirst();
        do {
            Contact c = new Contact();
            String name = people.getString(indexName);
            String number = people.getString(indexNumber);
            Log.d("number", "" + number);
            c.setDisplayName(name);
            c.set_phoneNumber(number);
            contactList.addContact(c);
        } while (people.moveToNext());
        people.close();
        return contactList;
    }
```

But when i try this code on HTC desire c it can't work. 
any body can tell me Why. ?
what is actual problem. and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 import java.lang.reflect.Array;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Collections;
 import java.util.Comparator;
 import java.util.List;

 import android.R.bool;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.provider.Contacts.Phones;
 import android.provider.ContactsContract;
 import android.text.Html;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

 import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
 import com.google.ads.AdView;

 public class button extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

private ListView listView;
private List<ContactBean> list = new ArrayList<ContactBean>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);





    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
            null, null);

    while (phones.moveToNext()) {

        String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

        String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));



        ContactBean objContact = new ContactBean();
        objContact.setName(name);
        objContact.setPhoneNo(phoneNumber);
        list.add(objContact);

    }
    phones.close();

    ContanctAdapter objAdapter = new ContanctAdapter(button.this,
            R.layout.alluser_row, list);
    listView.setAdapter(objAdapter);

    if (null != list && list.size() != 0) {
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<ContactBean>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(ContactBean lhs, ContactBean rhs) {
                return lhs.getName().compareTo(rhs.getName());
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(button.this).create();
        alert.setTitle("");

        alert.setMessage(list.size() + " Contact Found!!!");

        alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alert.show();

    } else {
        showToast("No Contact Found!!!");
    }
}

protected boolean isNullValue(String input)
{
    if(input==null)
    {
        return true;            
    }
    else
        return false;
}

private void showToast(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listview, View v, int position,
        long id) {
    ContactBean bean = (ContactBean) listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
    showCallDialog(bean.getName(), bean.getPhoneNo());
}

private void showCallDialog(String name, final String phoneNo) {
    AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(button.this).create();
    alert.setTitle("Call?");

    alert.setMessage("Are you sure want to call " + name + " ?");

    alert.setButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alert.setButton2("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String phoneNumber = "tel:" + phoneNo;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri
                    .parse(phoneNumber));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    alert.show();
}

public class ContanctAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContactBean> {

    private Activity activity;
    private List<ContactBean> items;
    private int row;
    private ContactBean objBean;

    public ContanctAdapter(Activity act, int row, List<ContactBean> items) {
        super(act, row, items);

        this.activity = act;
        this.row = row;
        this.items = items;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(row, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        if ((items == null) || ((position + 1) > items.size()))
            return view;

        objBean = items.get(position);

        holder.tvname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvname);
        holder.tvPhoneNo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvphone);

        if (holder.tvname != null && null != objBean.getName()
                && objBean.getName().trim().length() > 0) {
            holder.tvname.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getName()));
        }
        if (holder.tvPhoneNo != null && null != objBean.getPhoneNo()
                && objBean.getPhoneNo().trim().length() > 0) {
            holder.tvPhoneNo.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getPhoneNo()));
        }
        return view;
    }
}

public class ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvname, tvPhoneNo;
}

public class ContactBean {
    private String name;
    private String phoneNo;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhoneNo() {
        return phoneNo;
    }

    public void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    }

}
 }
```

Comment: What is the difference between both solutions? I can only see that you're not supplying a projection. Is that really the trick?
Some explanation what was wrong with Vivek's solution and why your solution fixes this would be appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140746/sqlite-looks-like-movetonext-works-without-movetofirst-needed