# Stumped as to how this ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception is being thrown

Tags: android, android-cursor

I have an `AsyncTask` that queries a content provider and does some additional processing in the `onPostExecute()` of that task. I have a stack trace for an exception that is very hard to reproduce, but I would like to guard against the condition or fix the code. The code is below:

```
int i = 0;
mIds = new long[cursor.getCount()];
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    mIds[i++] = cursor.getLong(COLUMN_ID);
}
```

The crash is happening on the line in the loop. The way I see it, the only way this could happen
is if:

1. `cursor.getCount()` is returning an incorrect count.
2. `cursor` is changed while this loop is executing, but I don't think that's possible
   because `cursor` is a local variable. Perhaps something underlying the `cursor` has changed that I'm not aware of.
3. `mIds` has changed. This shouldn't be possible because we are running
   on the UI thread and this is the only place in which that variable is assigned
   a new value. By the nature of `onPostExecute` running on the UI thread, it shouldn't be possible for this code to be running somewhere else at the same time, right?

Am I missing something?

Comment: Log the length of `mIds` just before the loop. Then place a conditional break at the assignment to mIds[i++] and break if `i >= mIds.length`. When it breaks, you can check whether `mIds` was reassigned somehow, whether `cursor` changed length, or what else might be going on.

Comment: I don't currently log this information and have been unable to reproduce (got one bug report), so I'm hoping I can add code to guard against the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to see what is wrong with that loop without seeing the full code but I note from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html):

> Cursor implementations are not required to be synchronized so code using a Cursor from multiple threads should perform its own synchronization when using the Cursor.

Comment: Out of all the answers, I think this one is the closest. It made me go look a little deeper at the code. The loop is actually in a method called from `MyAdapter.changeCursor(cursor)` AND the method that contains the loop is called AFTER `super.changeCursor(cursor)`. `changeCursor()` is the method that is called in `onPostExecute()`. Now, my thinking is that after the `super.changeCursor()` the cursor becomes available to other threads accessing the adapter and those threads must be resetting the position during my loop.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
int i = 0;
mIds = new long[cursor.getCount()];
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    mIds[i] = cursor.getLong(COLUMN_ID);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you think moving the i++ will make a difference here?

Comment: well i believe its adding before being used.  so hence it would start at 1 (as opposed to 0) and end at +1 over where it should be.  i could be wrong and dont have a compiler in front of me to test

Answer (score 0):

Drawing from my experiences, I always do it like this. Seems to avoid most problems.

```java
Cursor cursor = null;

try
{
    cursor = getDb().rawQuery(query, params); // your call to database here...
    if (cursor == null || cursor.getCount() == 0)
        return false;

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    mIds = new long[cursor.getCount()];
    int i = 0;

    do
    {
        mIds[i] = cursor.getLong(COLUMN_ID);
        i++;
    } while (cursor.moveToNext())
} catch(Exception e) {
    // Do error handling
    return false;
}
finally
{
    closeCursor(cursor);
    cursor = null;
}

return true;
```

Here's backup for my approach:
[Is Android Cursor.moveToNext() Documentation Correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985753/is-android-cursor-movetonext-documentation-correct)
[Does finally always execute in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/in-java-does-return-trump-finally)

Comment: Thanks. That'll avoid the force close, but I'm more interested in understanding why this exception is happening than masking it.

Comment: Yeah, it's always good to understand. Anyway, I recall I had issues with the `moveToNext()`... Try this: add `moveToFirst()` before while, then change while to do-while. See if that helps. Plus I'd also take the `i++` away from the `mIds[i++]`.